# Excess work done on call (perhaps wrong Dfun type) with scipy.integrate.odeint

Tags: python, scipy, physics, odeint

I'm writing a code in Python that predicts the energy levels of Hydrogen which I will use as a template for research into quarkonium energy levels. I'm using the `scipy.integrate.odeint()` function to solve the Shroedinger equation and it works fine for the lower energy levels up to `n=6`. I don't expect I'll have much need to go beyond that, but odeint returns `Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type).` which only encourages me to extend what I can predict.

The Shroedinger equation substitution I'm using is:

```
u'' - (l*(l+1)/r**2 - 2mu_e(E-V_emag(r))) * u = 0
=>
u' = v
v' = ((l*(l+1))/(r**2) - 2.0*mu_e*(E - V_emag(r)))*u
```

I'm then using `scipy.integrate.odeint()` on it and iterating through energies and using other functions I've defined that assess turning points and nodes in the result. The way I find the energy levels is finding the lowest possible E value where the number of turning points and nodes matches what it should; then incrementing `L` by 1 and finding the new ground energy, e.g. if `L=0` I'll find `n=1` energy and if `L=3`, I'll find the `n=2` energy.

Once the code increments to `L=7` it doesn't return anything useful. The range of `r` has been extended but I've tried with keeping it the same to reduce the number of steps but to no avail. The code is self-taught so in my research I've read about Jacobians. I'm afraid I haven't worked out what they are or if I need one yet. Any ideas?

```
def v_emag(r):
    v = -alpha/r
    return v

def s_e(y,r,l,E): #Shroedinger equation for electromagntism
    x = numpy.zeros_like(y)
    x[0] = y[1]
    x[1] = ((l*(l+1))/(r**2) - 2.0*mu_e*(E - V_emag(r)))*y[0]
    return x

def i_s_e(l,E,start=0.001,stop=None,step=(0.005*bohr)):
    if stop is None:
        stop = ((l+1)*30-10)*bohr
    r = numpy.arange(start,stop,step)
    y = odeint(s_e,y0,r,args=(l,E))
    return y

def inormalise_e(l,E,start=0.001,stop=None,step=(0.005*bohr)):
    if stop is None:
        stop = ((l+1)*30-10)*bohr
    r = numpy.arange(start,stop,step)
    f = i_s_e(l,E,start,stop,step)[:,0]
    f2 = f**2
    area = numpy.trapz(f2,x=r)
    return f/(numpy.sqrt(area))

def inodes_e(l,E,start=0.001,stop=None,step=(0.005*bohr)):
    if stop is None:
        stop = ((l+1)*30-10)*bohr
    x = i_s_e(l,E,start,stop,step)
    r = numpy.arange(start,stop,step)
    k=0
    for i in range(len(r)-1):
        if x[i,0]*x[i+1,0] < 0: #If u value times next u value <0,
            k+=1               #crossing of u=0 has occured, therefore count node
    return k

def iturns_e(l,E,start=0.001,stop=None,step=(0.005*bohr)):
    if stop is None:
        stop = ((l+1)*30-10)*bohr
    x = i_s_e(l,E,start,stop,step)
    r = numpy.arange(start,stop,step)
    k = 0
    for i in range(len(r)-1):
        if x[i,1]*x[i+1,1] < 0: #If du/dr value times next du/dr value <0,
            k=k+1               #crossing of du/dr=0, therefore a maximum/minimum
    return k

l = 0
while l < 10:    #The ground state for a system with a non-zero angular momentum will
    E1 = -1.5e-08    #be the energy level of principle quantum number l-1, therefore
    E3 = 0           #by changing l, we can find n by searching for the ground state
    E2 = 0.5*(E1+E3)
    i = 0
    while i < 40:
        N1 = inodes_e(l,E1)
        N2 = inodes_e(l,E2)
        N3 = inodes_e(l,E3)
        T1 = iturns_e(l,E1)
        T2 = iturns_e(l,E2)
        T3 = iturns_e(l,E3)
        if N1 != N2:# and T1 != T2: #Looks in lower half first, therefore will tend to ground state
            E3 = E2
            E2 = 0.5*(E1+E3)
        elif N2 != N3:# and T2 != T3:
            E1 = E2
            E2 = 0.5*(E1+E3)
        else:
            print "Can't find satisfactory E in range"
            break

        i += 1
    x = inormalise_e(l,E2)
    if x[((l+1)**2)/0.005] > (x[2*((l+1)**2)/0.005]) and iturns_e(l,E2+1e-20)==1:
        print 'Energy of state: n =',(l+1),'is: ',(E2*(10**9)),'eV'
        l += 1
    else:
        E1 = E2+10e-20
```

Comment: Can you show  your code?

Comment: Doesn't this Schrödinger equation have an analytical solution, by the way?

Comment: I know it has an analytical solution, but it doesn't have an analytical solution for a strong force potential, so I'm using the known results for Hydrogen to make sure my code is working before I use it for quarkonium.

Comment: Never worked with the Schrödinger equation before, but it can be said the ``odeint()`` only works for "well-behaved" functions, i.e., the values of all derivatives should not be too high. As far as I can see, you have a pole at zero, resulting in very large values near 0, which causes numeric instabilities.

Comment: I've actually used a substitution of u(r) = r*psi(r) to avoid the problems of the undefined nature at r=0. This means that I've actually controlled the instability (and simplified the equation). When plotted with a non-zero l value, the value of the wave-function is zero at r=0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is wrong with your code and I'm not entirely sure what your `while i<40:` loop is doing, so perhaps you can correct the following if I'm wrong.

If you want the wavefunctions for a certain `n, l` for this system you can calculate the energy as E = RH/n^2 where RH is the Rydberg constant, so you don't need to count nodes. If you do need to count nodes, then the number corresponding to the `(n,l)` is `n-l-1`, so you can vary E and watch the number of nodes change for fixed l.

The main problem, it seems to me is that your r range isn't large enough to encompass all of the nodes (for large n ~ l), and that `odeint` doens't know to stay away from the *other* (unphysical) asymptotic solution, psi ~ exp(+ cr), and so under some conditions sends psi off to ±infinity for large r.

If it's at all helpful, this is what I came up with to find numerical solutions to the SE equation: you need to vary the `r`-range according to `n,l` though to avoid the above problems (eg see what happens if you ask for `n, l = 10, 9`).

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint

m_e, m_p, hbar = sp.constants.m_e, sp.constants.m_p, sp.constants.hbar
mu_e = m_e*m_p/(m_e + m_p)
bohr = sp.constants.physical_constants['Bohr radius'][0]
Rinfhc = sp.constants.physical_constants['Rydberg constant times hc in J'][0]
RHhc = Rinfhc * mu_e / m_e

fac = sp.constants.e**2/4/sp.pi/sp.constants.epsilon_0

def V(r):
    return -fac/r

def deriv(y, r, l, E):
    y1, y2 = y
    dy1dr = y2
    dy2dr = -2*y2/r - (2*mu_e/hbar**2*(E - V(r)) - l*(l+1)/r**2)*y1
    return dy1dr, dy2dr

def solveSE(l, E, y0):
    rstep = 0.001 * bohr
    rmin = rstep
    rmax = 200*l * bohr         # 
    r = np.arange(rmin, rmax, rstep)
    y, dydt = odeint(deriv, y0, r, args=(l,E)).T
    return r, y, dydt

n = 10
l = 2
y0 = (bohr, -bohr)
E = -RHhc / n**2
r, psi, dpsi_dr = solveSE(l, E, y0)

import pylab
pylab.plot(r, psi)
pylab.show()
```

Comment: The `while i<40` section is a binary interpolation procedure that finds which values of `E` give solutions that don't shoot off to infinity (although it always will, 40 steps is enough to home in on the true value to the precision I need). I'm aware that `En = -RHhc / n**2` but the point is that using Hydrogen is practice for using the same method for the strong force, where that relationship doesn't hold. My original question was just about stopping the odeint function doing excess work and not returning me a value.

Comment: And the section `if stop is None` then it will adjust the end of the range in accordance with increased energy level